# Find all the tables and column which has email in Oracle

Tags: oracle

In my Oracle database I have around 2K tables and want to find the table and column name which has email in it.

Condition: May not be column name would have `email` tag inside it but the value contained by the column is `<something>@<anything>.<tail>`.

Took help from previous similar thread, it is running without any output

```
DECLARE
    l_cmd     VARCHAR2 (2000);
    l_found   INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR eachcol IN (  SELECT *
                        FROM all_tab_cols a
                       WHERE a.data_type = 'VARCHAR2'
                         AND owner = 'SEARCHSCHEMANAME'
                    ORDER BY table_name, column_name)
    LOOP
        l_cmd   :=
               'select count(*) c from '
            || eachcol.owner
            || '.'
            || eachcol.table_name
            || ' where '
            || LOWER (eachcol.column_name)
            || q'[ LIKE '%@%.%' AND ROWNUM = 1]';

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_cmd INTO l_found;

        IF l_found > 0
        THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
                   RPAD (eachcol.owner || '.' || eachcol.table_name || '.' || eachcol.column_name, 92)
                || ' may contain email addresses'
            );
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_cmd);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
        RAISE;
END;
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't produce any output, then:

- there are no columns that contain such data
- there are no errors either
- you forgot to enable serveroutput

I slightly modified your code so that it

- selects data from `user_tab_cols` (didn't feel like trying `all_tab_cols`)
- contains inner `BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END` block which handles possible exceptions, but lets loop to continue (why would I want to stop execution on error? Nope, I want it to go on)

It kind of works in my schema, so I presume that it should work in yours too (unless you hit one or more of 3 possibilities I mentioned at the beginning).

```
SQL> SET LINESIZE 200
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_cmd    VARCHAR2 (2000);
  3     l_found  INTEGER;
  4  BEGIN
  5     FOR eachcol IN (  SELECT *
  6                         FROM user_tab_cols a
  7                        WHERE a.data_type = 'VARCHAR2'
  8                     --                         AND owner = 'SEARCHSCHEMANAME'
  9                     ORDER BY table_name, column_name)
 10     LOOP
 11        BEGIN
 12           l_cmd :=
 13                 'select count(*) c from '
 14              --            || eachcol.owner
 15              --            || '.'
 16              || eachcol.table_name
 17              || ' where '
 18              || '"' || eachcol.column_name || '"'
 19              || q'[ LIKE '%@%.%' AND ROWNUM = 1]';
 20
 21           EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_cmd
 22              INTO l_found;
 23
 24           IF l_found > 0
 25           THEN
 26              DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
 27                    RPAD (                                         --eachcol.owner || '.' ||
 28                          eachcol.table_name || '.' || eachcol.column_name, 92)
 29                 || ' may contain email addresses');
 30           END IF;
 31        EXCEPTION
 32           WHEN OTHERS
 33           THEN
 34              DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_cmd);
 35              DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
 36        --RAISE;
 37        END;
 38     END LOOP;
 39  END;
 40  /
```

Result:

```
LOGS.LOG1                                                      may contain email addresses
OBR1_IN.E_MAIL                                                 may contain email addresses
OBR2_IN.E_MAIL                                                 may contain email addresses
...
RPRT_OP.E_MAIL                                                 may contain email addresses
RPRT_PO.E_MAIL                                                 may contain email addresses

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I am running it from Oracle SQL Developer Tool, and yes there are tables and column which has email value. I have updated the question about the output.

Comment: Try to display L_CMD unconditionally (i.e. for every LOOP round) so that you'd see what is being executed. Then you'll be able to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use quoted identifiers to ensure that your identifiers have the correct case (rather than using `LOWER` and unquoted identifiers which Oracle will implicitly convert back to upper-case, which seems pointless);
2. You can also check other data-types including `CHAR`, `NVARCHAR2` and `NCHAR`; and
3. Ensure that `DBMS_OUTPUT` is enabled:

Like this:

```sql
DECLARE
  l_cmd   VARCHAR2 (2000);
  l_found INTEGER;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE();
  FOR eachcol IN (
    SELECT owner,
           table_name,
           column_name
    FROM   all_tab_cols
    WHERE  data_type IN ('VARCHAR2', 'CHAR', 'NVARCHAR2', 'NCHAR')
    AND    owner = 'SEARCHSCHEMANAME'
    ORDER BY
           table_name,
           column_name
  )
  LOOP
    l_cmd := 'SELECT COUNT(*)'
         || ' FROM   "' || eachcol.owner || '"."' || eachcol.table_name || '"'
         || ' WHERE  "' || eachcol.column_name || '" LIKE ''%@%.%'''
         || ' AND    ROWNUM = 1';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_cmd INTO l_found;

    IF l_found > 0 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
        RPAD (eachcol.owner || '.' || eachcol.table_name || '.' || eachcol.column_name, 92)
        || ' may contain email addresses'
      );
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_cmd);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
    RAISE;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yZE5msQg)